# Remove class from element

Tags: jquery

I need to remove one of the classes in menu to disable submenu. I tried hide submenu with CSS but even after that I had a problem with the main menu flickering. Therefore I need to disable class `.ext` from `li`

Using jQuery I tried to remove it in many ways and none of them work. I'm a beginner in using jQuery therefore I am searching for help

```html
<li class="menu-item-695 ext splitted">
  <a href="/napoje/" title="Drinks">
    <b>Drinks</b>
    <span class="submenu-arrow"></span>
  </a>
</li>
<li class="menu-item-695 splitted">
  <a href="/napoje/" title="Drinks">
    <b>Drinks</b>
    <span class="submenu-arrow"></span>
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/removeclass is what you need to use. If that's not working we need to see the JS you wrote in order to debug it

Comment: basically I copied whole path trought DevTools wich was this :
("#navigation > div > ul > li.menu-item-695.ext.splitted"), then i used removeClass like this:$("nav#navigation > div > ul > li.menu-item-695.ext.splitted").removeClass("ext") and it didnt worked

Comment: That works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/vwk5ntus/. *Assuming* 1) you've reference the libraries properly. 2) the selector is correct for the DOM structure 3) you're running the JS code after the DOM has loaded.

Comment: It finally works, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("li").removeClass("ext");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("li.menu-item-695").removeClass('ext');
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure JavaScript

```
let elements=document.querySelectoAll('li');
[].forEach.call(elements, function(li) {
  li.classList.remove('ext', 'other1', 'other2');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".menu-item-695").removeClass('ext');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this.
    $("li").removeClass("ext");